# How to remove the extra vertical blank space from a WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, window

How can I remove the blank space?

```
<Window x:Class="AnnoCopyDialog.RebarPasteWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AnnoCopyDialog"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Background="#f0f0f0"
        FontSize="11"
        Title="Paste Window"  Width="420" Height="Auto">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="0 15 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="70"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

Comment: Just change the window height to what ever size you want. Auto meant to be full height.

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain That's my problem! I want the window to auto-size to what is inside it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use SizeToContent="Height"**

```
<Window x:Class="AnnoCopyDialog.RebarPasteWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AnnoCopyDialog"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Background="#f0f0f0"
        FontSize="11"
        Title="Paste Window"  Width="420" Height="Auto" SizeToContent="Height">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="0 15 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="70"/>
            </StackPanel>


        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks! You saved me!